# jquery validate - form doesn't remember input text for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-validate

I have a form on my website, that is being validated by jquery validate plugin. Everything with this form's validation works fine except when I try to fill this form after submission, there isn't an option in autocomplete list, that I have already submitted. My code goes:

```
     <form class="order-form" id="customer-info">
          <input required type="text" name="customer_name" autocomplete="on">
          <input type="tel" name="customer_phone" autocomplete="on">
          <input type="text" name="customer_address" autocomplete="on">
          <input required type="email" name="customer_email" autocomplete="on">
      </form>
```

JS:

```
  coast.find("#customer-info").validate({
        rules: {
            customer_name: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            customer_phone: {
                required: true,
                specialChars: true
            },
            customer_address: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return !coast.find("[id^='radio-1']").is(':checked');
                },
                address: true
            },
            customer_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            element.addClass("form-error");
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            orderForm = $(form).serialize();
            // sending data width ajax
            return false;
        },

        onfocusout: false,
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
            }
        }
    });
```

First I thought the problem was with missing `form.submit()` in `submitHandler`. But then I found this link: http://jsfiddle.net/0g0oaonL/2/. There is no `form.submit()` and autocomplete works perfectly fine.
Submit button is out of `form`, maybe that causes the problem?

### Edit

The code for submitting:

```
   $("button").on("click", function () {
        if (coast.find('#customer-info').valid() && someOtherConditions == true) {
            $(this).find('span, img').toggle();
            $('#customer-info').submit();
            $.ajax({
                // just sending some data
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: If your `submit` button is outside the `form` container, where is the code that is triggering the validation/submit?  What autocomplete are you talking about?  Please, if you want our help, then you need to do a better job writing the question and constructing the demo.

Comment: It appears that the autocomplete you're talking about is the one that is totally controlled by each browser and its specific settings.  You will have no control over this with JavaScript, and it's very unlikely that your JavaScript is breaking it.  It's just up to how each browser decides to work.

Comment: @Sparky I am talking about simple browser autocomplete, when you submitted a form, then you come back next time and start typing same text and it shows your previously submitted text in a suggestion box below the input. I also added code that is triggering the validation/submit.

Comment: @Sparky autocomplete works fine on all the other sites, browser settings are ok

Comment: You're asking about the autocomplete that is solely a function of the browser.  There is nothing wrong with jQuery Validate and there is nothing we can do here.

Comment: @Sparky then why Chrome, for example, doesn't remember input data only from this one particular site? I looked through all permissions for this site and everything is ok (I even compared them with the ones for another site, where autocomplete works fine). If this behaviour is caused by the browser, what can be the reason for it?

Comment: I have no idea, except that this has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.